# Dark mode in Eclipse changes the color of the drop down menu text making it unreadable. How do I fix this?

Tags: eclipse, themes

[image: The text in the Window tab is white on a white background]

I'm new to using Eclipse and programming softwares in general, so more thorough explanations would be appreciated!

How do I change the text back to a dark color to read it, and is it possible to make the background grey and keep the text white?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the Eclipse version you are using, Dark theme may differ:

- Under Eclipse Bar Menu Window, select Preferences
- From the Preferences Window, Select General -> Appearance
- From the drop down Theme, select one of the available "Dark" themes

You could also click here on the Restore Default button to revert all changes you have tried then Click on Apply button

Must restart Eclipse to be effective.

[image]

**Following is the Default Dark Theme when using Old Eclipse 2019-09**
[image: Old Eclipse]

**Following is the Default Dark Theme when using New Eclipse 2020-12**
[image]

Comment: Although changing back to light mode fixes the problem, I was wondering if I could keep dark mode on while changing the text in the drop down box readable. I want to keep my actual background dark theme, but I want to specifically change the drop down menu text. Any way to fix this?

Comment: I am afraid that Menu Bar is an OS configuration thing that cannot be changed from Eclipse itself, you should change the os window config/theme to make it work

Comment: @QASpecialist This is no longer true since Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17): https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/platform.php#dark-win32-menu

Comment: You're right @howlger  New eclipse versions have a betting DARK theme that overwrite the Menu Bar Color and Font.  Latest Eclipse can be found at the following: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/installer   Java 11 required

Comment: An installation of Java 11 or higher is only required when you do not use the [embedded Java 15 that is now shipped as part of the most Eclipse IDE packages](https://www.eclipse.org/justj/).

Comment: So it looks like I have the latest Eclipse version and the latest version of Java as well. I checked this by checking for updates in the Eclipse help>check for updates. I also know I installed the latest version of Java 15. If the version isn't the problem, what is? Perhaps I checked the version incorrectly?

Comment: @Sam Ahn What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: @Sam Ahn If you still have the problem on Eclipse 2020-12 running java 11, the problem is most likely to be related to Window 10 Theme from an old build prior to Build 18282.  I suggest you try to reset the Windowd 10 Themes from the following url: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/86376-turn-off-color-filters-screen-windows-10-a.html  If it is still not working, you probably need to update to the latest build for free at  https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of having light background and light text in the menu dropdowns.

Fixed by cycling the Windows theme from custom to "Windows" then back to a dark these. This was done in Personalization -> Themes in Windows 10. Now, the dropdowns are dark with legible text.